# content script is not working when using gmail?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I used permission and match URL both are same but not working mail.google.com URL
working any other website

manifest screen shot shown below

[image: manifest file screen short]

Comment: i run many chrome extensions same style using manifest file why is not working ?

Comment: Because Gmail is a [Single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_page_application). Once loaded, it does not really "load" (in the classical sense) again when you navigate to a different page. Instead, the reference fragment ("location hash") is changed to modify the history state, without unloading the page. See the answer at the duplicate question for a solution.

Comment: very very Thanks....  Rob W